# How to count just a first sale by a client in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have a spreadsheet with clients first purchase I want to see how many new clients a month we are getting. However some of the clients we sell too could have the same name in a different zip code for example miami clinic could be in both florida and ohio so I want them counted individually. I also want to see the total new clinics per month. but if a clinic purchases in january and again in march i only want that january purchase counted

Comment: You could create a simple tableau function to combine the text of the name and zip code to create a unique ID for each clinic and then group by that. And then write some (more complex) function to select the first purchase date for each clinic. All very doable.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO.  You actually need a cohort analysis in Tableau.  Not that difficult.  Share some of your sample data for demostration, please.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your sample data be like

[image]

Now create a calculated field `first purchase date` as

```
{Fixed [Clinic Name], [Zipcode]: min([Sale Date])}
```

This field will give each clinic its first purchase date only.  Check it

[image]

Now to create a filter for `first purchase date` create a calculated field say `first purchase filter` as

```
[first purchase date] = [Sale Date]
```

Adding `TRUE` value filter (and don't forget to add the filter to context by right clicking it) will give sale amount in first purchases

[image]

OR use this filter for differentiation also

[image]

For any further query please share your actual data structure with a few rows and desired output in respect of those sample rows.